# Network remains disabled on every reboot

Tags: networking, kubuntu, network-manager, 23.04

I am using Kubuntu 23.04. A couple of days back I tried to upgrade to the 23.10 version. It failed due to some issue with the grub-loader location. Anyway. I managed to downgrade my system back to 23.04 with no data loss. But since that day, I have been facing a networking issue. My networking is disabled since then. On every reboot I need to run the following commands to get it to work.

```
sudo ip link set enp0s31f6 up
sudo dhclient enp0s31f6
sudo systemctl restart smbd
sudo systemctl restart nmbd
```

Yes, for some reason my samba share also doesn't work unless I restart the services on every reboot. As a temporary fix, I can live with this but it is infuriating. I have tried several fixes but none of them seem to fix my issue.

I tried reinstalling Network Manager but it didn't work.
The `/etc/network/interfaces` file was missing so I created and added the following code.

```
auth enp0s31f6

auto lo enp0s31f6
iface lo inet loopback

iface enp0s31f6 inet dhcp
```

This didn't work either.

The `/etc/netplan` directory had only one file - `01-network-manager-all.yaml` and it had the following content.

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

I changed it to

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
     enp0s31f6:
        dhcp4: true
```

But this didn't work either.

Here is the output of the `sudo systemctl status NetworkManager` command.

```
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-12-15 13:59:12 IST; 18min ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
   Main PID: 789 (NetworkManager)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 28624)
     Memory: 7.1M
        CPU: 81ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
             └─789 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

Dec 15 13:59:12 wfh NetworkManager[789]: <info>  [1702628952.5578] ifupdown: guessed connection type (enp0s31f6) = 802-3-ethernet
Dec 15 13:59:12 wfh NetworkManager[789]: <info>  [1702628952.5692] dhcp: init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
Dec 15 13:59:12 wfh NetworkManager[789]: <info>  [1702628952.5694] manager: (lo): new Loopback device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
Dec 15 13:59:12 wfh NetworkManager[789]: <info>  [1702628952.5735] manager: (enp0s31f6): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Dec 15 13:59:12 wfh NetworkManager[789]: <info>  [1702628952.5779] failed to open /run/network/ifstate
Dec 15 13:59:12 wfh NetworkManager[789]: <info>  [1702628952.5812] manager: startup complete
Dec 15 13:59:12 wfh NetworkManager[789]: <info>  [1702628952.5872] modem-manager: ModemManager available
Dec 15 13:59:26 wfh NetworkManager[789]: <info>  [1702628966.4424] agent-manager: agent[e6db1e7db18d032b,:1.46/org.kde.plasma.networkmanagement/1000]: ag>
Dec 15 14:00:19 wfh NetworkManager[789]: <info>  [1702629019.5368] device (enp0s31f6): carrier: link connected
Dec 15 14:00:20 wfh NetworkManager[789]: <info>  [1702629020.5622] failed to open /run/network/ifstate
```

The `/run/network/ifstate` file is missing as you can see.

Here is the status of the `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status` command.

```
Status: install ok installed
```

Here is the status of the `dpkg -l | grep linux` command.

```
ii  binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu                     2.40-2ubuntu4                                        amd64        GNU binary utilities, for x86-64-linux-gnu target
ii  console-setup-linux                           1.217ubuntu3                                         all          Linux specific part of console-setup
ii  libselinux1:amd64                             3.4-1build4                                          amd64        SELinux runtime shared libraries
ii  libv4l-0:amd64                                1.22.1-5build1                                       amd64        Collection of video4linux support libraries
ii  libv4lconvert0:amd64                          1.22.1-5build1                                       amd64        Video4linux frame format conversion library
ii  linux-base                                    4.5ubuntu9                                           all          Linux image base package
ii  linux-firmware                                20230323.gitbcdcfbcf-0ubuntu1                        all          Firmware for Linux kernel drivers
ii  linux-generic                                 6.2.0.20.20                                          amd64        Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers
ii  linux-headers-6.2.0-20                        6.2.0-20.20                                          all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 6.2.0
ii  linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic                6.2.0-20.20                                          amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-6.2.0-39                        6.2.0-39.40                                          all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 6.2.0
ii  linux-headers-6.2.0-39-generic                6.2.0-39.40                                          amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic                         6.2.0.20.20                                          amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic                  6.2.0-20.20                                          amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic                  6.2.0-26.26                                          amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.2.0-32-generic                  6.2.0-32.32                                          amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.2.0-33-generic                  6.2.0-33.33+1                                        amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.2.0-34-generic                  6.2.0-34.34                                          amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.2.0-35-generic                  6.2.0-35.35                                          amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.2.0-36-generic                  6.2.0-36.37                                          amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-6.2.0-39-generic                  6.2.0-39.40                                          amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic                  6.5.0-14.14                                          amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic                           6.2.0.20.20                                          amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-libc-dev:amd64                          6.2.0-20.20                                          amd64        Linux Kernel Headers for development
ii  linux-modules-6.2.0-20-generic                6.2.0-20.20                                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-6.2.0-26-generic                6.2.0-26.26                                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-6.2.0-32-generic                6.2.0-32.32                                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-6.2.0-33-generic                6.2.0-33.33                                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-6.2.0-34-generic                6.2.0-34.34                                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-6.2.0-35-generic                6.2.0-35.35                                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-6.2.0-36-generic                6.2.0-36.37                                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-6.2.0-39-generic                6.2.0-39.40                                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-6.5.0-14-generic                6.5.0-14.14                                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.5.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-20-generic          6.2.0-20.20                                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-26-generic          6.2.0-26.26                                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-32-generic          6.2.0-32.32                                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-33-generic          6.2.0-33.33                                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-34-generic          6.2.0-34.34                                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-35-generic          6.2.0-35.35                                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-36-generic          6.2.0-36.37                                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-39-generic          6.2.0-39.40                                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-14-generic          6.5.0-14.14                                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.5.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-470-6.2.0-20-generic     6.2.0-20.20                                          amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.2.0-20
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-470-6.2.0-26-generic     6.2.0-26.26+2                                        amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.2.0-26
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-470-6.2.0-32-generic     6.2.0-32.32                                          amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.2.0-32
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-470-6.2.0-33-generic     6.2.0-33.33+3                                        amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.2.0-33
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-470-6.2.0-34-generic     6.2.0-34.34+1                                        amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.2.0-34
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-470-6.2.0-35-generic     6.2.0-35.35                                          amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.2.0-35
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-470-6.2.0-36-generic     6.2.0-36.37+1                                        amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.2.0-36
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-470-6.2.0-39-generic     6.2.0-39.40                                          amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.2.0-39
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-470-6.5.0-14-generic     6.5.0-14.14                                          amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-14
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-470-6.2.0-20-generic     6.2.0-20.20                                          amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.2.0-20 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-470-6.2.0-26-generic     6.2.0-26.26+2                                        amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.2.0-26 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-470-6.2.0-32-generic     6.2.0-32.32                                          amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.2.0-32 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-470-6.2.0-33-generic     6.2.0-33.33+3                                        amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.2.0-33 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-470-6.2.0-34-generic     6.2.0-34.34+1                                        amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.2.0-34 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-470-6.2.0-35-generic     6.2.0-35.35                                          amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.2.0-35 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-470-6.2.0-36-generic     6.2.0-36.37+1                                        amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.2.0-36 (objects)
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-470-6.2.0-39-generic     6.2.0-39.40                                          amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.2.0-39 (objects)
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-470-6.5.0-14-generic     6.5.0-14.14                                          amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-14 (objects)
ii  linux-signatures-nvidia-6.2.0-39-generic      6.2.0-39.40                                          amd64        Linux kernel signatures for nvidia modules for version 6.2.0-39-generic
ii  linux-signatures-nvidia-6.5.0-14-generic      6.5.0-14.14                                          amd64        Linux kernel signatures for nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-14-generic
ii  linux-sound-base                              1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu7                                 all          base package for ALSA and OSS sound systems
ii  pptp-linux                                    1.10.0-1build3                                       amd64        Point-to-Point Tunneling Protocol (PPTP) Client
ii  util-linux                                    2.38.1-4ubuntu1                                      amd64        miscellaneous system utilities
ii  util-linux-extra                              2.38.1-4ubuntu1                                      amd64        interactive login tools
```

I have no idea what else to try. Let me know if you need any more information. This is how my networking status icon looks even after enabling the network using commands.

[image: networking system tray icon kubuntu 23.04]

And this I had to create manually the first time I saw networking option missing. Creating this did nothing.

What to do now?

[image: network system settings menu]